# Finding changesets in mercurial by grepping the patch

Tags: mercurial

Is there a way in mercurial to find a change by giving a pattern in the edit (the changed code), as opposed to the log message or filename?

I've looked pretty thoroughly in "hg help revsets" and I think there's not a good way to do this.  Here's the best hack I came up with, but I'm hoping I missed a capability, or that someone can do a little better.

`hg log -M -u goldberg -p | grep '(^changeset:\|<pattern>)' | grep -C 1 '<pattern>'`

(and then manually selecting the revision number for later work with those revisions)

Comment: since I've tweaked my own suggestion a bit (as a zsh function.  should work in bash) I thought I'd follow up.  Also adding some discussion below....    hg_find_patch () {hg log -M -u goldberg -p --style default | grep '\(^changeset:\|^[+-].*'${1}'\)' | grep -B 1 ${1}}

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You should take a look at [`hg grep`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#grep).

> ```
> Search revisions of files for a regular expression.
>
> This command behaves differently than Unix grep. It only accepts
> Python/Perl regexps. It searches repository history, not the working
> directory. It always prints the revision number in which a match appears.
>
> By default, grep only prints output for the first revision of a
> file in which it finds a match. To get it to print every revision that
> contains a change in match status ("-" for a match that becomes a non-match, 
> or "+" for a non-match that becomes a match), use the --all flag.
>
> Returns 0 if a match is found, 1 otherwise.
> ```

You can type `hg grep --help` for more informations.

Comment: This gets me closer.  If I understand right, hg grep will tell you whether the whole file contains or doesn't contain a pattern (so you can see when that whole-file-fact changed).  I'm looking for all of my edits that have that pattern.  For instance I could pick a variable I was working with for a week and pull up all those relevant changesets, even though the variable's been around for years.  Am I right that hg grep can't quite do that?

Comment: You can use the `--all` to search all changesets in the repository or `-r` to specify a range of revision. For example, if you do `hg grep --all "$myvariable" path/tofile.php`, mercurial will look in all revisions of the given file for the pattern "$myvariable" printing corresponding revision where he found the pattern for the first time.

Comment: I did a comparison between my hack and hg grep and was surprised, so I think I'm still misunderstanding grep --all. I'd mistakenly thought that grep --all would skip cases where the pattern was already in the file but a line with the pattern changed.  In fact hg grep catches *more* changes than the shell script, including some changesets where no line with the pattern change.  I thought perhaps it was returning every changeset that touched a file with the pattern, but it does not return all of those, so the behavior is still confusing to me.  It does get all I need though, (and more)