# In mercurial how can I find changesets that contain a string?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Let's say I have the following revisions:

```
rev 1:
+ Dim Foo as integer

rev 2:
+ I like big butts, I cannot lie

rev 3
- Dim Foo as integer
```

**Foo** is in rev 1 & 2, and removed from three.  What command can I issue that will return all changesets that **Foo** was added or deleted?

Ideally I'd like to be able to do this from toroisehg as well

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding changesets in mercurial by grepping the patch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330782/finding-changesets-in-mercurial-by-grepping-the-patch)

Comment: Foo is content of file, filename or text in commit message?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the [`grep`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#grep) command :

```
hg grep --all Foo
```

To address Lazy Badger concerns in comments.

```
$ hg init
$ echo "Dim Foo as integer" > test 
$ hg commit -m "1"
$ echo "I like big butts, I cannot lie" > test 
$ hg commit -m "2"
$ echo "Dim Foo as integer" > test 
$ hg commit -m "3"
$ hg grep --all Foo
```

The output of the grep command is :

```
test:2:+:Dim Foo as integer
test:1:-:Dim Foo as integer
test:0:+:Dim Foo as integer
```

Which means, `Foo` was first seen in the file test on revision 0 (the `+` sign tells us that), then it dissapeared on revision 1 (the `-` signs), and reappear again on revision 2.

I don't know if it is what you want, but it clearly indicates revision on which the searched word was added or deleted.

Comment: BTW: grep returns **files, not changesets**. OP asked "all changesets..."

Comment: @LazyBadger You can see that grep does exactly that, telling us on which revision the searched pattern appears and disappears

Comment: I would like changesets, but this does sort of get me there.

Comment: how would one easily match revision to changeset?

Comment: @NickJ, you can output changeset hashes by using an output template like `-T "{node}\n"`. I've posted an answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`hg grep --diff PATTERN [FILE]...`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/hg.1.html#grep) to search in diffs, and [specify a template](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#template-usage) to print the changeset specifically.

This answer is no more than an update of @krtek's excellent answer. It contains a few examples more, and it uses the modern `--diff` flag rather than the `--all` flag, which was deprecated since krtek answered. Both flags do the same thing: instruct `hg grep` to search all diffs for the given pattern.

Here are three example invocations and outputs. (The script to create the example repository is at the end of this post.)

##### Ordinary grep

```
$ hg grep --diff Foo 
myfile:2:+:Dim Foo as integer
myfile:1:-:Dim Foo as integer
myfile:0:+:Dim Foo as integer
```

##### Use a template to extract commits' revision numbers and hashes

```
$ hg grep --diff Foo -T '{rev}:{node|short}\n'
2:2c425adcc0b1
1:5a46fef3be7c
0:b8d4a0cc48a5
```

##### See all available data/templating fields

```
$ hg grep --diff Foo -T json
[
 {
  "change": "+",
  "date": [1662367225, -7200],
  "lineno": 1,
  "node": "2c425adcc0b1fdcdea5ab8c0a864ce0af4a80478",
  "path": "myfile",
  "rev": 2,
  "texts": [{"matched": false, "text": "Dim "}, {"matched": true, "text": "Foo"}, {"matched": false, "text": " as integer"}],
  "user": "Lady MacBeth <ladymcb@globe.local>"
 },
 // ...
]
```

---

Commands to set up the example repository, used in the examples above:

```
# Create the repository
hg init
touch myfile
hg add myfile

# Create 3 commits
echo "Dim Foo as integer" > myfile
hg commit -m "1"
echo "Tomorrow, and tomorrow, and tomorrow" > myfile
hg commit -m "2"
echo "Dim Foo as integer" > myfile
hg commit -m "3"
```