# HG: find where a deleted line was removed

Tags: mercurial, blame

I am looking for the mercurial equivalent of the solution to this question:

[How do I "git blame" a deleted line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404444/how-do-i-blame-a-deleted-line)

In short, I am looking at a mercurial commit where a line was added, and in the current revision this line is no longer present, and I want to find when and why it was removed.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725856/in-mercurial-how-can-i-find-changesets-that-contain-a-string).

Comment: wonderful, this helped me get from `hg show 9876:tip path/to/file | grep --all "pattern" -U20` to `hg grep -r 9876:tip "pattern" path/to/file`, which was just what I needed.  If you give that as an answer I'll accept it.  Originally I tried it without `--all`, thinking that it was a substitute for the -r flag, but found that it only lists the first revision unless `--all` is specified.

Comment: Thanks for the offer, Brian, but I only pointed you to an existing answer which solved it. Write up a short answer and [give krtek an upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9726648/715075) :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`hg histgrep`  will let you search a change log for a pattern, such as a deleted string.  If you are looking for more than just the first occurrence, be sure to include the `--all` flag.  For me it looked something like this:

`hg histgrep --all -r 9876:tip "pattern" path/to/file`

Thanks to Anton for the helpful comments and krtek for his [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725856/).

Comment: `hg grep` has been renamed to `hg histgrep` in the meantime. besides that the answer is still valid.

Comment: @stigli: It has? I can't find any reference to that, even in latest Mercurial (3.8.3+).

Comment: @stigi: `hg histgrep` doesn't appear to exist in hg 4.5.3. `hg grep` still works.

Comment: @stigi Confirming `hg histgrep` is present in my version of Mercurial 4.4.2. Running `hg grep -h` shows "*For the old 'hg grep', which searches through history, see 'histgrep'.*"

Answer (score 1):

`hg log -p fileName > fileName.log`

Then open the `fileName.log` file

In there you will find commit the details of each commit along with the diff of that commit. The details of the commit includes the username.